# TabHost: how to start an activity in another TabGroupActivity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

My application contains a TabHost with 3 Tabs: 
Tab 1: activity 1, activity 2 ... 
Tab 2: activity A, activity B ...

I am using the google tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

When I am in activity B, I want to launch, when I click on a button, the activity 1. The problem is the activity is launched in Tab2 and not in Tab1. Any idea to launch it in the good tab?